# MySQL query find out current status by looking at history logs

Tags: mysql

Database tables:

services (id, name)

history (id, service_id, status, message,smessage, date) where status is integer from 0 to 4.

I am trying to figure out the current statuses of each distinct service_id based on the history for that service. 
When a maintenance is scheduled it is entered into the database with future start and end time, and until now I was using this to figure out the status:

```
SELECT
    d. NAME,
    d.id,
    c.date,
    COALESCE (c.smessage, 'Normal') AS smessage,
    COALESCE (c. STATUS, 0) AS STATUS
FROM
    services d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        history
    WHERE
        id IN (
            SELECT
                max(id)
            FROM
                history
            WHERE
                date < now()
            GROUP BY
                service_id
        )
) c ON d.id = c.service_id;
```

However, when there is overlapping maintenance, or when there is a maintenance scheduled two weeks in advance, and another maintenance gets scheduled for next 15 minutes, the second maintenance does not display correctly.

sample data

```
# id  service_id date status message added_by smessage
126 19  2014-10-21 11:32:34 0   Regular Status update.  usr1    Regular update.
125 19  2014-10-23 22:00:00 0   Maint1 done.    usr1    Maint1Done.
124 19  2014-10-23 17:00:00 3   Maint2 done.    usr1    Maint2 done.
123 19  2014-10-21 22:00:00 0   Maint3 done.    usr1    Maint3 done
122 19  2014-10-21 17:00:00 3   Maint3 Sched.   usr1    Maint3 sched
121 19  2014-10-20 22:00:00 0   Maint2 sched.   usr1    maint2 sched 
120 19  2014-10-20 17:00:00 3   Maint1 sched.   usr1    Maint1 sched
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your output to be?

Comment: Current status for each service ID.

Comment: Yea, but what does that mean in the case where you have multiple scheduled maintenance like in your question?

Comment: It sounds the `max(id)` filter picking the maintenance record that's scheduled furthest out. If you want the earliest record, you'll probably want to avoid using the `max` aggregate function and use `order by` and `limit 1`.

Comment: In the case of multiple maintenance scheduled it should display the message and the status of the maintenance that ends soonest.

Comment: I'm not certain how you are getting both a start date and an end date shoehorned into this table.  Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right basic structure, you just need to use `date` instead of `id`:

```
SELECT s.NAME, s.id, s.date,
       COALESCE(h.smessage, 'Normal') AS smessage,
       COALESCE(h.STATUS, 0) AS STATUS
FROM services s LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT h.*
      FROM history
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM history h2
                        WHERE h2.service_id = h.service_id and
                              h2.date < now() and
                              h2.date > h.date
                      )
      ) h
      ON s.id = h.service_id;
```

The `not exists` is saying:  "Get me history records for a given service where there are no later history records."  That is equivalent to getting the last one.

Comment: if I use date, there will be a lot of overlapping ones. I need to search by both date and id if possible.

Comment: @Dimitri . . . You really need to search by start time; I figured that what what the `date` column really contains.  Just use that column.  (You say:  "entered into the database with future start and end time" but don't provide fields for those.)

Comment: oh ya, my bad. Basically it creates 2 entries in database with future time.

Comment: The issue that I am running into with this is somewhat similar to what I used to have. It finds the latest message and thinks that everything is fine, without realizing that there is another maintenance going on. Basically as of right now it seems that the only way out is to make a separate table for maintenance or a flag. However your solution is something that I am going to use for now while I create a proper one. Thanks.